# Here API icons customization.

Tags: android, here-api

I'm using here Android SDK and try to customize my map. I wondering, can I change map icons somehow? I mean such icons at the map:

[image][image][image]

I can change CategoryIcons from here api search, but didn't find where to change the map icons.

Answer (score 0):

These icons are baked into the core resource library. It is not something an external developer can change.